# Auto resizing JButtons when resizing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, autoresize

I am using WindowBuilder and I created a `JFrame` with many `JButton` components and I would like to see my buttons resize automatically. The only solutions that I found is by using `GroupLayout`, is any other way to do it with any layout (I am using absolute layout)?

Comment: Yes, there are a variety of layouts that can achieve that. Which one (or ones) to use depend on the required effect. Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: BTW - Absolute layout is a `null` layout pretending to be a layout - don't use it *ever*. `GroupLayout` is only really useful when using a GUI builder and is hard to edit later by hand. Don't use a GUI builder until you understand how the inbuilt layouts work, and how they can be combined.

Comment: The JButtons can get larger with a larger JPanel, but the font size of the JButtons will remain the same.  If you want a completely dynamic layout, you'll have to calculate the appropriate JButton text font size as well.  A GridLayout will make the JButtons larger on a larger JPanel.